# How do I manipulate specific components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS. I'm generating a sorting visualizer. What I did

```
function Box(props){
    return(<span x={props.xyz} className="box">
        {props.data}
    </span>)
}


const [mynums,setMynums] = useState([7,1,3,12,25,2,5,0])
  let numsList = mynums.map( (item,index) =>{
    return <Box data={item}  key={index} xyz={index}></Box>
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App">
        {numsList}
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically I have Box with value inside based on my array.

I'm having trouble to select a specific box to sort it.
I know we can add a onClick to get the props of the component, but what if theres all the components are generated through an array of data? I want to manipulate a specific component base on the index of the array.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show actual code to go with your verbal description. Also read [ask] for more tips to improve your question.

Comment: Your title and your body don't seem to mesh well. "Best practice" questions generally fare poorly on Stack Overflow, because they are perceived to be asking for opinions (best practice being opinions of people who write books and blog posts). If you have a specific question, please ask that.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out just now that even though we use ReactJS , the fundamentals of WebAPI is still there.

To select a specific DOM from a State that holds Array.

Since i render the component all have the same class.

```
//To get the arrayBox
const arrayBox = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
thisBox[index].style.backgroundColor = "red";
setTimeout(() => { setMynums([...mynums]); }, 2000);
```